# Xamarin.Forms: Android <Entry> and dependency service?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, decimal, numeric

I am learning C# and Xamarin.Forms at the moment, so please treat me like a complete beginner.

I have an entry in my XML in Xamarin.Forms:

```
<Entry x:Name="temperature" Placeholder="Temperatur" Keyboard="Numeric" Margin="20,0"/>
```

In my CS:

```
double temp = double.Parse(temperature.Text);
```

This all works fine. But I need to use a different kind of entry for Android. Because Xamarin.Forms Entry do not handle decimal separators very well when it comes to Samsung phones.

On Android I want to use NuGet "NumericEditText-Xamarin.Android" like this:

```
<br.com.akamud.NumericEditText 
android:id="@+id/txtNumeric"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="number|numberDecimal" />
```

It should handle my entry input, and then of course handle the entry after that with the shared code of Xamarin.Forms. Is dependency service the best way to go about solving this?
Would someone be so kind to help me out in the right direction.

Comment: you should use a Custom Renderer to do this, not DependencyService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency service is used to invoke native api on specific project, if the issue is related to UI, a custom renderer is the better choice.

You need to create a custom renderer for a custom view, and replace the view with NumericEditText inside the custom renderer.

#### Create Custom View

```
public class EntryView : View
{
}
```

#### Usage of Custom view in page

```
 xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:App2"
 <local:EntryView/>
```

#### Custom renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EntryView), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace App2.Droid
{

    public class MyRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer<EntryView, NumericEditText>
    {

        Context _context;
        NumericEditText editView;
        public MyRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<EntryView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(e.NewElement != null)
            {
                if (Control == null)
                {
                    editView = new NumericEditText(Context);
                    editView.InputType = InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal|InputTypes.ClassNumber;
                    SetNativeControl(editView);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view.

Comment: Hi ,did my answer help or not ?

Comment: Hi Cole! 

Im trying it out right now, you`ll hear from me soon

Comment: I am getting there. But where exactly do I put 'xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:nameOfMyApp" <local:EntryView/> . Putting it in my mainpage.xaml just adds another entry under my other entries. But I want to replace <entry> on android with the numericEditText.